# Convert YYYYMMDD to day of week in KSH

Tags: shell, ksh

Basically what I'm looking for is the output of 'date +%a' or 'date +%A' but don't want the current date I want to provide it a date. So it can read in a variable that has a value of '20180831' and would output 'Fri' or 'Friday'

Comment: Which are you using, bash or ksh?

Comment: Not that it matters. The `date` command isn't part of the shell, it works the same no matter what shell you run it from.

Comment: date -d 20180831 "+%a"

Comment: Use the `-d` option to provide an input date to use instead of the current time.

Comment: Did you try `man date` to see all the options?

Comment: I am using KSH not bash. It seems that -d option does not work

Comment: @BrianGurka, as Barmar told you five minutes earlier, `date` isn't part of bash *or* ksh; it's provided by your OS vendor, not by your shell. Telling us what shell you run doesn't let us know anything about which options your copy of `date` does or doesn't have; you need to tell us your OS vendor and release, or -- even better -- your specific `date` version, if it has a version number of its own.

Comment: ...btw, if `date` doesn't have the support you need, do you have a Python interpreter handy? Embedding a short Python script in your shell script is often a reasonable way to work around missing tools.

Comment: nvm. I was using one of our legacy servers. New dev server -d option works. Thanks :)

Comment: If you aren't interested in editing the question to specify the legacy server's OS (and thus make this a "convert YYYYMMDD to day of week on FooOS 3.5" question), you might consider deleting it -- right now, since there's insufficient details to allow an canonical answer, it's not adding much to the knowledgebase.